# Could not find the entrypoint _pcre2_compile@40. (3260)

Tags: c, openedge, progress-4gl, dynamic-library

I have built a libpcre2-8.dll with the help of [this](https://github.com/kiyolee/pcre2-win-build) Git Repo.

I'm now trying to access the function pcre2_compile from an ABL (Progress) program. (Progress is an old 4GL Language). I'm constantly hitting the error

```
Could not find the entrypoint _pcre2_compile@40. (3260)
```

I've already tried many things but it still doesn't work.

The Dynamic Library is 64 bit and Progress is also running in 64 bit.

In ABL (Progress) you can specify the LIBRARY-CALLING-CONVENTION but whether I set it to STDCALL or CDECL or just don't specify it, the error remains the same.

This is a snippet of the Progress ABL I'm trying to execute the function: (code comes from [this Git Repo](https://github.com/gabsoftware/Progress-ABL-4GL-Regex), which works, but only for 32 bit)

```
PROCEDURE pcre2_compile :
    DEFINE INPUT               PARAMETER pattern     AS CHARACTER. /* const char *          */
    DEFINE INPUT               PARAMETER options     AS INTEGER.   /* int                   */
    DEFINE       OUTPUT        PARAMETER errcodeptr  AS INTEGER.   /* int *                 */
    DEFINE       OUTPUT        PARAMETER errptr      AS MEMPTR.    /* const char **         */
    DEFINE       OUTPUT        PARAMETER erroffset   AS MEMPTR.    /* int *                 */
    DEFINE INPUT               PARAMETER tableptr    AS INTEGER.   /* const unsigned char * */
    DEFINE              OUTPUT PARAMETER result      AS MEMPTR.    /* pcre *                */

    DEFINE VARIABLE libName AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE hCall   AS HANDLE    NO-UNDO.

    libName = get-library().

    CREATE CALL hCall.
    ASSIGN
        hCall:CALL-NAME                  = "pcre2_compile"
        hCall:LIBRARY                    = "lib/libpcre2-8.dll"
        //hCall:LIBRARY-CALLING-CONVENTION = "STDCALL"
        hCall:CALL-TYPE                  = DLL-CALL-TYPE
        hCall:NUM-PARAMETERS             = 6
        hCall:RETURN-VALUE-DLL-TYPE      = "MEMPTR".

    hCall:SET-PARAMETER(1, "CHARACTER", "INPUT" , pattern    ).
    hCall:SET-PARAMETER(2, "LONG"     , "INPUT" , options    ).
    hCall:SET-PARAMETER(3, "HANDLE TO LONG"     , "OUTPUT", errcodeptr ).
    hCall:SET-PARAMETER(4, "MEMPTR"   , "OUTPUT", errptr     ).
    hCall:SET-PARAMETER(5, "MEMPTR"   , "OUTPUT", erroffset  ).
    hCall:SET-PARAMETER(6, "LONG"     , "INPUT" , tableptr   ).
    hCall:INVOKE().
    ASSIGN result = hCall:RETURN-VALUE.

    DELETE OBJECT hCall.

END PROCEDURE.
```

What am I missing?

Update: Checked with Dependency Walker and the functions seem to be visible. They do have a _8 suffix... But even when trying pcre2_compile_8 it still gives me the same error.

[image]

Comment: What's with parameter 3? I've not seen "HANDLE TO LONG" before.

Comment: It inappropriately applied stdcall decoration.  Valid only in 32-bit code, 64-bit has just one calling convention and therefore uses no decoration at all.  Only other thing you can do is hCall:LIBRARY-CALLING-CONVENTION = "CDECL"

Comment: If youre on active support I would consider contacting Progress!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that the name of the entry point was "pcre2_compile_8" instead of "pcre2_compile"... Wanted to delete the question because now it looks quite dumb but leaving it anyway...

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to change your long integers to INT64.

Comment: Mmmm. Good comment. Thought I would get another error in that case. Something like 'parameter mismatch'. But maybe it doens't find it because of the params. Will have a look. Thx.

Comment: Hi Tom, the parameters do not matter. I've tested this with a Hello World example getting one int parameter. I can pass a CHARACTER or 4 parameters instead of 1. It keeps on working and ignores the 3 extra parameters. So finding the C function does not depend on the parameters passed.

Answer (score 0):

Is the entrypoint externally visible/accesible?

I've used https://dependencywalker.com/ in the past to figure that out.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Does that change if you specify the `ORDINAL` option ?